# Filter partial JSON extractor response and send it as a request

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I am working on the Rest API performance testing and I'm handling the JSON responses for the requests. How to split the response partialy and send it to the next request

I did use the online tool for JSON extractor but nothing helped.

Sampler (Api) Response :
{
  "ResponseCode": "200",
  "Response" : "PON CFF2345 893939",
  "Message" : null
}

Based on the above response i used the JSON Extractor post processor and the json path expression as ($.Response)

Actual result : "PON CFF2345 893939"

But I want to extract the value only `CFF2345` and send that value to the next sampler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add after JSON extractor a [Regular Expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Choose `JMeter Variable Name to use` the JMeter variable you saved

Use `(\w+)` as Regular Expression Template `$1$` and Match No. 2 to get second string

Comment: Learned a new thing today. Thanks! Otherwise I would have used directly Regular Expression Extractor without JSON Extractor.